# Spark SQL query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a query for a twitter json file to extract the most influential person by looking at retweetCount. I need to group my output by the user, their time zone and the number of retweets in descending order. 
When I run the query below I keep getting the exception:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisExceptionorg.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve 'total_retweets' given input columns
>   t.retweeted_screen_name, t.tz, total_retweets, tweet_count;

```
sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT
     t.retweeted_screen_name,
         t.tz,
     sum(retweets) AS total_retweets,
     count(*) AS tweet_count
    FROM (SELECT
            actor.displayName as retweeted_screen_name,
            body,
        actor.twitterTimeZone as tz,
            max(retweetCount) as retweets
          FROM tweetTable WHERE body <> ''
          GROUP BY actor.displayName, actor.twitterTimeZone,
                   body) t
    GROUP BY t.retweeted_screen_name, t.tz
    ORDER BY total_retweets DESC
    LIMIT 10 """).collect.foreach(println)
```

When I try to simplify this query I run into errors like:

> Column total_retweets is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Will much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a SQL query, it does not calculate resolve the aliases for each query  until after the `WHERE`, `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses have run (but it does do so before any `HAVING` clauses). You therefore can't `ORDER BY` total_retweets, you will need to ORDER BY `sum(retweets)`